# NHibernate mapping self joined table?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, self-join

It might be very simple but I think I am missing something. I have a self joined table `Units`, every unit has a main unit:

[image]

So that I could query for something like this:

[image]

The table `units` is mapped to the following class:

```
public class Units
{
    public virtual int Unit_Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Unit_Value { get; set; } 
    public virtual Units Main_Unit { get; set; }
}
```

With .hbm mapping file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NewA.Domain"     namespace="NewA.Domain">
   <class name="NewA.Domain.Entities.Units,NewA.Domain" table="Units">
    <id name="Unit_Id" column="Unit_Id" type="Int32" length="4" unsaved-value="0"> 
      <generator class="native">
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Unit" column="Unit" type="string" length="50" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-one name="Main_Unit" class="NewA.Domain.Entities.Units,NewA.Domain"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When testing these entity with the following code:

```
Units unit = _UnitsRepository.GetById(2);
string parent_unitname = unit.Main_Unit.Unit;
Assert.AreEqual("pack",parent_unitname);
```

I got the following excpetion:

> ```
> Expected values to be equal.
>
> Expected Value : "pack"
> Actual Value   : "kg"
> ```

The problem is that the `Main_Unit` property of the `Unit` entity is referencing itself, so what I am missing here??, and how can I write something like recursive SQL CTE to apply ranks and so on, because I have the same problem with other more complex self joined tables with more complex queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need many-to-one mapping instead one-to-one.
Try this configuration:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NewA.Domain.Entities.Units.Units, NewA.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Units`">
    <id name="Unit_Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Unit_Id" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Unit" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Unit" />
    </property>
    <property name="Unit_Value" type="System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Unit_Value" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="NewA.Domain.Entities.Units.Units, NewA.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Main_Unit">
      <column name="Main_Unit_id" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I suggest you to try **Fluent NHibernate** - it can dynamically generate mappings for you.
Here's the configuration I used:

```
var fluent = Fluently.Configure()
    .Mappings(c => c.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Units>()
        .Override<Units>(u => u.Id(uu => uu.Unit_Id).GeneratedBy.Native())))
    .Database(() => SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("test.sqlite3"));

var configuration = fluent.BuildConfiguration();

// Generate database schema
new SchemaExport(configuration).Create(false, true);

var sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
// Now just open session and do whatever you need
```

Comment: why do i need many-to-one mapping insteed of one-to-one mapping??and where is the other part of the relation in your configuration,the one to many part?? the Main_Unit is referencing just only one Units enitty reference as i mentioned, there is only one table Units. and what is that coluumn Main_Unit_id in your configuration there is no Main_Unit table it is just only Units table.

Comment: **One-to-one** would mean that you won't be able to express **g** and **mg** in **kg** (i.e. something like 1000 g == kg, 1,000,000 == 1 kg). In your case many different 'fractional' units may be expressed in the same Main_Unit so you need **many-to-one**. **Main_Unit_id** references object **Units** (which is mapped to table **Units**), in your example this corresponds to the column **Main_Unit**. Fluent NHibernate just has this naming convention of appending **_id** for foreign key columns. You can override this convention the same way I did with Id generator